# How to execute a function after an element has been created

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a button that I want to click on every time create a new element with an id "box" and display it in the browser. Now I want to execute a function with callback function when I click on each box.
But I can't run it...

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function() {
  const element =  `<div class="box"> box ${count}</div>`;
  const position = "afterbegin";
  test.insertAdjacentHTML(position,element);
  count++;
})

// I want to execute this function with the callback function when I click on each element with the box class
function execute() {
  //some code
}
```

Comment: why not call execute() function inside the event listener ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless there is more to the question, why just not add a onClick handler when you add the div box ? and let it call execute();

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function() {
  const element =  `<div class="box" onClick="execute()"> box ${count}</div>`;
  const position = "afterbegin";
  test.insertAdjacentHTML(position,element);
  count++;
})
```

Comment: *"when I click on each box*"* ... OP is looking for new event listener

Comment: Ahh, i missted that - thanks, i've modified the answer accordingly